# iTunes Connect: App name with special characters (german 'umlaute')

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, diacritics

Today I wanted to submit a new german app with an 'umlaut' in app name: "Börse".
There are plenty of Apps in the AppStore with special characters "Diät, Führerschein" etc.

When I enter the app name a JavaScript onBlur event send the name to a server and then every special charcters are stripped out.

Can anyone confirm this problem? I tested it under OS X Snow Leopard, Windows 7, Chrome, Safari, Firefox. I also disabled JavaScript, but still no luck.

Screenshots:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2213241/Bildschirmfoto%202011-09-26%20um%2016.11.31.png

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2213241/Bildschirmfoto%202011-09-26%20um%2016.11.16.png

Anyone has a workround for this one? I also created a apple support ticket.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've kept the product name alphanumeric but used the Bundle Display Name in the Info.plist file to use additional/different characters.

I ran into a similar problem a while back with the + character - I couldn't sign any apps with the character in the bundle name. So, I changed the name from Xxx+ to XxxPlus and set the Bundle Display Name to Xxx+. Looked like I wanted it to in the GUI and the signing worked fine.

Comment: the Bundle Display Name works with special characters. But the App Store Title (iTunes Connect) not.

Comment: I confirm, same on my side - with special characters within the app name... As I remember, it has to be the completely fresh new "feature" by Apple, as it all worked well even yesterday...

Comment: It sounds like you're interested in the bundle display name using the umlaute which sounds doable- I think the point Jablair is making is that its name under iTunes Connect should affect the way the name appears on the user's device.

Comment: It's been a while since I submitted a new app to the store - I blanked on the App Store display coming from someplace other than the bundle display name.

Comment: there are some other developers who have the same problem. https://devforums.apple.com/thread/124377?tstart=0