# How do i put a trademark symbol on the app store?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I've tried this: `&trade;`, I've tried this: `&#8482;` and I've tried this: `&#x2122;`. Each and every time, they'll show up on the preview and on iTunes as the TM sign. But on the iPhone, it shows up in plain text. How do i do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type it in directly instead of as an HTML entity. On a Mac, hit the keys Option+2 (or just copy it: ™).

Comment: How is that even related to the question? :P

Comment: Why on earth did this get two upvotes and got accepted? It isn't even correct.

Comment: @Emil My understanding is that he's asking how to get a registration symbol in the description for an app submitting to the app store. The answers it to not use HTML, but type the character directly, for which the keys Option+R (®) work on my Mac. What isn't correct about it?

Comment: @yinkou On my Mac, Option+2 is ™. Shift+Option+D gives me Î.

Comment: @ceejayoz The question clearly asks for a Trademark-symbol, not registration-symbol.

Comment: Odd, I think a neuron died on me when I read the question. I'm guessing it was accepted for having pointed him in the right direction. Heh. Correcting.

Comment: Still pretty strange that it got two upvotes when it was very clearly wrong in the first place :p

Comment: Sry, have a german keyboard layout. There it is on shift+opt+d. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're supposed to be able to include those characters in your app name, but since it isn't working anyway, I suggest you don't.

Have you tried just typing the actual character into the name in iTunes Connect? (™) That might work. ( [iTunes Connect: App name with special characters (german 'umlaute')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556587/itunes-connect-app-name-with-special-characters-german-umlaute) )

Comment: I'm not putting it into the app name, i'm putting it into the app description. They seem to work fine for other people. Those and bullet points.

Comment: Okay, well try what I said, type the actual character instead of the HTML-code.